# Android app crashes on 2 of 3 screen resolution of galaxy s8

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, screen-resolution, galaxy

I'm building an android app that has 3 recycler views. They scroll horizontal and I add an inset, so I get my item centered (when it is the first, last or only one) on the screen.

To get the right value for the inset on different screen sizes, I get the width of the recycler view divided by 2, minus the item width divided by 2.

This works so far, unless you have a Samsung Galaxy S8/+, where you can choose different screen resolutions. HD+ 1480x720, FHD+ 2220x1080, WQHD+ 2960x1440

On HD+ there is no problem, but on the other 2, it will crash. I don't own a physical device like that and there seems to be no emulator for that.

Where could be the problem? Will it give me the wrong width?

```
int viewWidth = recyclerView.getWidth();
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                float logicalDensity = displayMetrics.density;


                    int calculateInset1 = viewWidth/2 - ((int) Math.ceil(57.5 * logicalDensity)); //57.5 is the item width divided by 2
                    recyclerInset decoration = new recyclerInset(calculateInset1);
                    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```

Comment: You should add your code so others can see what you are talking about.

Comment: crash logs might be helpful here....

Comment: added the code and I don't have the crash log. This happens on someones device, that is not close to me.

Comment: check the emulator?

Comment: With emulator it wont happen. Only on S8/+ where you can change the resolution by yourself.